# Custom validation for List<string> data annotation keeps showing other input that is not empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, tag-helpers

I am trying to create a required custom validation for List Data Annotation but when one of the input field is empty, the rest of the input that is bind to the data annotation also shows the error message as well even though its not empty.

I am trying to only show the error to its respective input that is empty.

**This is my view:**

```
<input name="ListName[0]" type="text" />
<span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ListName" data-valmsg-replace="true"/>

<input name="ListName[1]" type="text" />
<span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ListName" data-valmsg-replace="true"/>

 <input name="ListName[2]" type="text" />
<span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ListName" data-valmsg-replace="true"/>

<input name="ListName[3]" type="text" />
<span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ListName" data-valmsg-replace="true"/>

<input name="ListName[4]" type="text" /> 
<span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ListName" data-valmsg-replace="true"/>
```

**This is my model**

```
[Display(Name = "Name: ")]
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
[CannotBeEmptyAttribute(ErrorMessage = "Cannot leave name field empty")]
public List<string> ListName{ get; set; }
```

**This is my custom validation**

```
 public class CannotBeEmptyAttribute : ValidationAttribute
        {
            protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
            {
                var strings = value as IEnumerable<string>;

                foreach (var item in strings)
                {
                    if (item == null)
                    {
                        return new ValidationResult("Cannot leave name field empty");
                    }
                }

                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your validator method seems to be incorrect and I don't know why you need custom validator when you can use `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Cannot leave name field empty")]`

Comment: @derloopkat Hi, I can't use required because its a List<String> instead of String

Comment: You add custom validationAttribute on ListName,and in VIew,you bind the same validation with list[0],list[1],list[2]...,and in your custom validation,one of the list is null,it will fail,so as you say`but when one of the input field is empty, the rest of the input that is bind to the data annotation also shows the error message as well even though its not empty`.If you want to validate them,you can also use client-side validation to bind each one.

Comment: @YiyiYou yea, but how should return an error for those input that are empty? I dont want to show those error on input that is not empty

Comment: If you want to use client-side validation,you can do like this,`<form method="post">
    <label for="id">id:</label>
    <input type="text" id="id" name="id" required>
    <label for="id">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
    <input type="submit">
</form>`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which validation you want.

(1) the validation logic in your code

```
                foreach (var item in strings)
                {
                    if (item == null)
                    {
                        return new ValidationResult("Cannot leave name field empty");
                    }
                }
            
                 return ValidationResult.Success;
```

It returns warning when ListName have empty string.
It returns success when all strings are not empty,

(2) The opposite validation logic

```
                foreach (var item in strings)
                {
                    if (item != null)
                    {
                       return ValidationResult.Success;
                    }
                }

                 return new ValidationResult("Cannot leave name field empty");
```

It returns warning Only when the strings of ListName are all empty.
It returns success when ListName have at least one string not empty.